# PHP in_array() can't even match a single character. Strict is set to true

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I've seen a million of these threads here already, and read through every single one. That, plus some serious Googling.

**UPDATE:** I am rewriting this post to include complete code and explanation, so everyone understands what is going on and what I am trying to do.

I am developing using CodeIgniter, so some syntax may look weird if you are not familiar with it.

I have an link bar with letters A-Z. The idea is to find only "active" letters that have content in a particular column (mysql `LIKE $letter%`). With this information I would be able to "dim" certain "empty" letters if there are any, using CSS.

This function here queries mysql and gets each unique first letter of entries in a column. The result should be anywhere from 0 to 26 matches/array items.

```
  //From am_model.php              
  function getFirstLetter($domainId)
  {

   $q = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(alias_name, 1) 
                                     AS letter 
                                     FROM am_aliases 
                                     WHERE domain_id = '" . $domainId . "' 
                                     ORDER BY alias_name;");
   if($q->num_rows > 0):
    foreach($q->result() as $row) 
    {
     $result[] = $row;
    }
    //print_r($result); <-- prints out correct result.
    return $result;
   endif;

  }
```

After that, I call this function from a controller:

```
    $foundLetters = $this->am_model->getFirstLetter($domainId);
```

then define an `$alphabet` array.

```
    $alphabet = range('a','z');

    foreach($alphabet as $letter)
    {

         if(in_array($letter, $foundLetters, TRUE)):
                echo $letter . ' found<br />';
         else:
                echo $letter . ' not found<br />';
         endif;

    }
```

Nothing complicated. All I have to do is check if a single character in a loop matches my alphabet array.

As Col. Shrapnel suggested below, I did some debugging, and `dump()` of letters from $alphabet and $foundLetters arrays produce different results, so I guess it does point 
to possible encoding issues, which I am trying to figure out now...

Does anyone have any idea what the hell is going on here??

```
function dump(&$str) {
  $i=0;
  while (isset($str[$i])) echo strtoupper(dechex(ord($str[$i++])));

}
```

Here is the result from `dump()`:

```
a: $alphabet->61 613C6272202F3E<-$foundLetters
b: $alphabet->62 613C6272202F3E<-$foundLetters
c: $alphabet->63 683C6272202F3E<-$foundLetters
d: $alphabet->64 613C6272202F3E<-$foundLetters
```

and these:

```
print_r($alphabet); // all 26 letters

Array ( 
        [0] => a
        [1] => b
        [2] => c
        ...            
        [23] => x
        [24] => y
        [25] => z
 )

 print_r($foundLetters); // dynamic array.

 Array ( 
        [0] => b
        [1] => s
 )
```

Comment: did you try it without strict mode?

Comment: You shouldn't use more syntax then necessary, it clouds the meaning of your code. It is bad style to do so. I am not sure what your endif; token is doing there, it's a moot point, the colon : does not need toe xist after the foreach there either, nor does the : colon after the if.

Comment: `if(): /*statements*/ endif;` is an alternative to `if() {}` in PHP, if a bad one.

Comment: Have you posted your *actual* code? I doubt it since I would expect to see a semi-colon at the end of your `echo` statement. Please post your *actual* code and maybe we can identify a subtle bug that isn't apparent from what you've posted.

Comment: @Tom Dignan: ooops, after `foreach()`, its my mistake, but after `if()` it does, because i am not using `{}` there. PHP Alternative Syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php


@Sarfaz: did you miss `if(in_array($letter, $emptyLetters, true)):  // $strict is set` ?

Comment: @Asaph, no, not the actual code, and `:` after `foeach() ` is a typo

Comment: @Matthew Scharley: why is alternative syntax bad?

Comment: @solefald: The alternative syntax is mainly bad because so few people use it that it looks bizarre to most PHP programmers. It's also bad because the extra keywords clutter up the code.

Comment: @solefald: You still have typos in this fake code sample (no semi-colon at the end of your `echo` statement). Please post your *actual* code or you won't likely get the bottom of your problem.

Comment: @Alaph: this is pretty much the actual code. there is not much else to it. Trust me, there is nothing else is wrong with the code. And this is the only piece that is not working.

Comment: @solefald: There are enough BASIC style languages around. No language can be all things to all people, and sometimes I get a bad feeling that PHP is trying to be. Providing too many ways to do the same thing syntactically just confuses people who expect one way or the other.

Comment: @Matthew Scharley: I picked up PHP after a 10 year hiatus, so i know the regular syntax, but this seems cleaner to me. Plus im not really coding this for other people. Just a little project for myself.

Comment: I don't see `$allLetters` being defined...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

got your letters from the file, eh? :)

use `var_dump` instead or print_r and trim in comparison :)

**Edit**
Use this code to see what is going on

```
foreach ($alphabet as $letter) {
  foreach ($empty_letters as $empty) {
    dump($letter);
    echo " ";
    dump($empty);
    echo "<br>";
    if ($letter == $empty) {
      echo "$letter was found in \$empty_letters<br>\n";
      break;
    }
  }
}

function dump(&$str) {
  $i=0;
  while (isset($str[$i])) echo strtoupper(dechex(ord($str[$i++])));
}
```

Comment: Nope. From MySQL. `SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(alias_name, 1) AS letter FROM am_aliases WHERE domain_id = 'XXX' ORDER BY alias_name;` Basically finds every unique 1st letter from a column

Comment: @solefald so, it can be encoding issue. You have to debug a little. See my post update.

Comment: Hmm.. this is interesting. I get different values with left and right columns, but what the hell is it? haha

Comment: I am going to crash right now, but i think we are onto something here.... i get `61 643C6272202F3E`.. gonna dig deeper in the morning... thank you!

Comment: +1 I think this is a great answer because it provides a general debugging strategy, which applies to many scenarios, and teaches the lesson that what you see is not necessarily what you have.

Comment: Man, I wasted all this time, and all i had to do is to `trim()`; results right after the query. `$result[] = trim($row->letter);`

Answer (score 2):

Works for me

Comment: Yeah, this works for me to.. Looks like the issue is with how arrays are generated. As Col. Shrapnel mentioned below, it may have something to do with encodings...

Answer (score 0):

The only thing in your sample that is strange is the : that comes after the foreach - followed by curly braces will cause a syntax error.  Is that the problem, or does your program just not output anything?

Comment: I agree with Tom - I tried this exact script and I got the expected results.  Can you specify what exactly happens when you run yours?  Does nothing show up?  Some sort of warning/error?

Comment: Nothing. Absolutely nothing. I  ran it through the loop with `var_dump()` and got `bool(false)` for every letter. but there is one difference. You guys are manually setting the array, mine is dynamically generated. But i did `trim()` on every letter. and even printed out with `''` around each one.

Comment: Dynamic generation shouldn't matter unless the variable types are getting screwed up somehow.  Can you post your exact code?

Comment: Just posted in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I got the expected results as well. But I think your example array is different from what you are actually passing through. Give this a try...

```
 foreach(array_values($alphabet) as $letter){
     echo $letter . '<br />'; // Correctly prints out every letter from $alphabet.
     if(in_array($letter, $emptyLetters)) {  // $strict is set
         // do something
         echo 'found';
     }
 }
```